# How to split query groups into frequencies/occurrences in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have some data with only 3 attributes

name
illness
yes/no

I'm interested in the frequency of how many times someone has been ill from a set group of viruses whether its once, twice, thrice.

So I end up with a table like this

```
Frequency - Count
F1            300
F2            121921
F3            121
F4            2
F5+           2323
```

This is some of the code I tried to write. The bit I am stuck on is how do I tell SQL that when a person hasnt been exposed to the virus give them a score of 0, if its once then 1, twice then 2.

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN F0 = 0 THEN 'F0'
     WHEN F1 = 1 THEN 'F1'
     WHEN F2 = 1 THEN 'F2'
     wHEN F3 = 3 THEN 'F3'
     WHEN F4 = 4 THEN 'F4'
     WHEN F5 >= 5 THEN 'F5
    END   AS Virus_Frequency,
  COUNT(*)                                AS VIRUS_COUNT

FROM
(
    SELECT
      distinct name,
      SUM(CASE WHEN illness in (43598435, 24343, 45413, 2455, 54574511, 2074123, 34351153) THEN 0 END)   AS F0,
```

Comment: "I have data with only three attributes."  And none of them are named `user_id` or `virus_id`, so I'm really confused.  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: sorry accident when I was re-typing into this. I cant share sample data as its medical data. Desired result would be the illness I've grouped as virus (43598435, 24343, 45413, 2455, 54574511, 2074123, 34351153)      which are numbers signifying different viruses. I've chose to group these as they belong to the same family of viruses.     I'd just like a frequency table of how many times someone may have been ill from a virus in these groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a histogram of histograms query:

```
SELECT VIRUS_COUNT, COUNT(*) as person_count, MIN(user_id), MAX(user_id)
FROM (SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) as VIRUS_COUNT
      FROM t
      WHERE Virus_id in (43598435, 24343, 45413, 2455, 54574511, 2074123, 34351153) 
      GROUP BY user_id
     )  t
GROUP BY VIRUS_COUNT
ORDER BY VIRUS_COUNT;
```

I include sample user ids in such a query, just so there are references for further investigation.